# ユーザー名のクラスを作成したい

Tags: monaca

ニフティのmBaaSを使っています。クラス名をそれぞれのユーザー名にすることでデータの管理を行いたいと思っています。そこで、クラス名をログイン中のユーザー名にするために以下のようなコードを書いたのですが、

```
var currentUser = NCMB.User.current();
var Name = currentUser.get("userName");

var Name = NCMB.Object.extend("Name");
var name = new Name();
```

クラス名がNameという名前になってしまいます。どうすればログイン中のユーザーの名前でクラス名を付けれますかね？

Comment: ニフティのドキュメント(http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/assets/sdk_doc/javascript/jsdoc/symbols/NCMB.Object.html)を確認したところ、「NCMB.Object.extend("Name");」にて、ニフティが用意したクラスを使用しているので、クラス名自体を変更するのはできないと思います。もし無理やりでもやるのであれば、独自にクラスを作成して、そのクラスに、ニフティのNameクラスへの参照を持たせる方法になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var Name = NCMB.Object.extend("Name");
> ```

"Name"だとStringの"Name"になっちゃうからそのまま作ってしまうのではないですかね
`""`を外せばいけそうな気がしますけど

Comment: 試してみたところ無事うまくいきました。ありがとうございます！！